# How to drop duplicates while using write.partitionBy in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe which looks like below:

```
|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|    Name    |   Type    |  Attribute 1  |  Attribute 2  |
|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|   Roger    |     A     |     X         |       Y       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|   Roger    |     A     |     X         |       Y       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|   Roger    |     A     |     X         |       Y       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|   Rafael   |     A     |     G         |       H       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|   Rafael   |     A     |     G         |       H       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|   Rafael   |     B     |     G         |       H       |
|------------|-----------|---------------|---------------|
```

I want to partition this dataframe and save it to disk based on name and type

The line of code currently looks like this,

```
df.write.partitionBy("Name", "Type").mode("append").csv("output/", header=True)
```

The output gets saved correctly buts has duplicated rows as mentioned below

In folder

/output/Roger/A

```
|---------------|---------------|
|  Attribute 1  |  Attribute 2  |
|---------------|---------------|
|     X         |       Y       |
|---------------|---------------|
|     X         |       Y       |
|---------------|---------------|
|     X         |       Y       |
|---------------|---------------|
```

/output/Rafael/A

```
|---------------|---------------|
|  Attribute 1  |  Attribute 2  |
|---------------|---------------|
|     G         |       H       |
|---------------|---------------|
|     G         |       H       |
|---------------|---------------|
```

/output/Rafael/B

```
|---------------|---------------|
|  Attribute 1  |  Attribute 2  |
|---------------|---------------|
|     G         |       H       |
|---------------|---------------|
```

As you can see, this csv contains duplicates. How do I remove these duplicates while using write.partitionbY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.distinct()` before writing.

```
df.distinct().write.partitionBy("Name", "Type").mode("append").csv("output/", header=True)
```

Comment: Will this do the drop after patitionBy or before? Spark tends to drop the Name and Type column when doing a write.partitionBy which creates the duplicate columns.

Comment: It drops duplicates before writing as a csv. So you should not see any duplicates in your output file. Yes, Spark won't write the `name` and `type` fields as they are already in the partitionBy clause.